# geth option "--allow-insecure-unlock", what exactly does it mean?

Tags: security, blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum

The doc on github says:

> --allow-insecure-unlock             Allow insecure account unlocking when account-related RPCs are exposed by http

And, I have to add the option when start `geth`, otherwise can't unlock the account.

---

### Questions

- What does this option exactly mean? I read the doc and searhed on Google, still can't fully understand it.
- Is it safe to use this option, will it create security holes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you access to a node with geth via HTTP protocol you can´t unlock account with personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.account, password). If you try, you'll receive error "**account unlock with HTTP access is forbidden**". So, to avoid that you have to use the flag ***allow-insecure-unlock***.

That is because the unlock operation is unsafe if the node is exposed to external. That "protection" was added in go-ethereum in PR #17037 (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/17037)